# jquery event handler working locally but not online

Tags: jquery, local

For some reason, the event handler I've created for a "read more" button (a jquery toggler for sliding) works locally, but not online. I've checked the resources tab in developer tools and it does load, and the file path appears correct as well. Anyone know why this isn't happening?? Thank you!!

here's the link:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62523661/kusama/index.html

It's under "script.js" and the appropriate class is "toggled_content." 
Thank you SO MUCH in advance!

Comment: That's a great site, lovi'n it! Open the console. and notice it's all red, everywhere, a bunch of files not loading, and errors etc.

Comment: @adeneo thx man!! It's a rookie move, but thats how we learn, right? I owe u a combo no.5

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to load jQuery over `http`, while the site is `https`. Browsers generally don't like that and won't allow it for security purposes.

Try loading the `https` jQuery instead: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js`

Also, make sure any other outside scripts you're calling are called over `https`.